# Extra Thread decreases FPS in LibGDX Java

Tags: java, multithreading, libgdx

I am using a Thread to do some calculations related to the app that need to be done simultaneously but this Thread causes the FPS to drop (logically) and I wanted to know how to resolve the issue as the Thread is not doing any heavy calculations at all. Here is the code where I implement the Thread and the Thread itself.

```
        incrementMass = new IncrementMass();
        incrementMass.start();
        // I added some extra functionality to the InputProcessor but I assume that is irrelevant
        if(InputProcessor.isButtonUp() && InputProcessor.getButtonLetGo() == RIGHT && !isJustPressed) {
            isJustPressed = true;
            try {
                incrementMass.join();
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            planets.add(new Planet(10, m, mouseOnWorld2.x, mouseOnWorld2.y));
        } else if(Gdx.input.isButtonJustPressed(RIGHT)) {
            isJustPressed = false;
            incrementMass.restart();
        }
```

The Thread:

```
/**
 * Thread to increment the mass in a while loop.
 */
public class IncrementMass extends Thread {
    /**
     * Increments the mass when started.
     */
    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();
        while(Gdx.input.isButtonPressed(Input.Buttons.RIGHT)) {
            MainScreen.m += 100;
            System.out.println(MainScreen.m);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Resets the mass so the whole thing starts over (for the creation of a new planet)
     */
    public void restart() {
        MainScreen.m = 100000;
    }
}
```

All this is called in the render() function of my Screen by the way.
I have one idea as to what is causing this: Every frame I create a new Thread which is not optimal but everything else I tried failed to actually perform my calculations correctly. It definitely solves the FPS problem to have the initiation of the Thread and the ´start()´ function in the constructor of my Screen but that for some reason messes with the incrementing of the mass and makes it a fixed value: the value I reset it to in ´restart()´
I've been trying to solve this but I'm baffled so here I am.

Comment: I think the most obvious idea is that the calculations here are so simple, the overhead of running the thread eats up any possible savings in time.  This is obviously something that would be better to do in the main thread of execution.

Comment: Yeah I thought of that too. The only reason I even use Threads is because while loops cause hangs in the render functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comment, there was no function for `isButtonJustUp()` which made it not be able to run sequentially. Therefore I made a Thread *so that* it was sequential which is not a good implementation of Threads. I've come up with a solution:

```
        if(Gdx.input.isButtonPressed(RIGHT)) {
            m += 100;
        } else if(InputProcessor.isButtonJustUp() && InputProcessor.getButtonLetGo() == RIGHT) {
            planets.add(new Planet(10, m, mouseOnWorld2.x, mouseOnWorld2.y));
            m=0;
        }
```

I haven't made `isButtonJustUp()` yet but it is the best way rather than implementing an unnecessary Thread.